# How to copy old cached RSS feeds and download to a text file?

Tags: rss

I am looking to copy and download all the old RSS feeds of a particular website.

Is there a way to copy all the old RSS feeds of a website and copy into a text or Microsoft Word file?

Comment: What do you mean by "old"?  You mean you want to keep a copy of them before they become unavailable, or you want to get old ones that are now unavailable?

Comment: "old" meaning if a site started in 2008, so all the rss feeds dating back to 2008 till now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have established that that RSS feeds are available, then you can use wget to obtain the RSS feed contents.  You will just need the URL of the feed corresponding to each time period that the feed covers.

RSS feeds usually terminate in .rss or .xml, so an example would be:

```
wget http://thewebsite/2008/01/01/therssfeed.rss -O thewebsiterssfeed20080101.txt
```

This saves the RSS feed found the this url to a text file.  Note that RSS feeds can overlap so some de-duplication may be required.